# Unity3d input field not GUI

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d.
For GUI I am using 3d mesh with orthographic Camera (not Unity GUI).
Is exists way to implement Input Text Field (without using Unity GUI)?

Comment: You want the Input Text Field to appear on your mesh?

Comment: I want Input Field in 3d Scene

Comment: Why not use an existing solution like NGUI (which in principle will be more or less equivalent to the upcoming new Unity GUI). It's  more or less what you'll need to create if you want to do it yourself. It's of course possible (a quad per char and such), but I'd avoid the trouble.